# How to List posts from custom post types using wp_list_pages() function with custom field title?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

## Problem

I want to list posts from a **custom post type** using **wp_list_pages()** function. 
Also, I want to use custom field to appear in place of the title of the post.

> Currently, I am using the following code to do this, but it does not incorporate the current_post class.

```
    $posts_list = new WP_Query($args);  

    while($posts_list->have_posts()){

        $posts_list -> the_post(); 

        the_field('custom_field_title');

            wp_reset_query();
    
    //currently there is no endwhile, yet loop is working
```

kindly suggest me an appropriate solution. Thanks.
Here is the page link: [Page Link](https://www.tutsinsider.com/)

solved now